# When were files moved to trashbox?

Tags: file-management, buffalo-nas

In my office we run a number of Buffalo NAS drives for file storage. These drives all have the 'trashbox' enabled, in short a recycle bin for the network shares.

Periodically I need to clean out the trashbox in order to reclaim disk space

I'd like to delete files form the trashbox that were moved there 1 month ago, or earlier. Is there any way I can see when these files were deleted and moved into this trashbox?

I've run a quick test and it doesn't seem like any of the file attributes change when they get moved here, so how can I identify the oldest ones?

Comment: does it not have a 'date added' attribute?

Comment: I'm accessing this form Windows Explorer, all the Date attributes tie up with when my test file was created, and now ehen I deleted it from the original fodler and it got automatically moved to the trashbox. Date, Date modified, date created, date accessed and date last saved are all unchanged

Comment: ah, OK - sorry I'm not really familiar with that as a setup; I'm on Mac, which adds a 'date added' attribute when something goes to trash

Comment: Your question has been here a few months with no real solution.  Is this still an open issue, did you solve it, or was it overtaken by events?  I don't know if the trashbox behaves exactly the same in all versions of Windows.  Just in case, it might be worth mentioning what version you're using.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this will be a little bit helpful to you. I am having the same issue.  I want to delete very old files from the trashbox.

I found this discussion (by googling, which is how I found your question).

One method is to use CMD window and emulate DOS functions. (if you are doing PC's for over 30 years you will know what this is).  The other is to create a script, which is not something that I know how to run, but I will keep looking.

Here is the link:
http://forum.buffalo.nas-central.org/viewtopic.php?t=22592

Comment: Welcome, and thanks for trying to help with this question.  The site works a little different from a forum.  Its purpose is to build a knowledgebase of questions and answers, so answers are intended to be definitive solutions to the question, and self-contained here rather than the site being a collection of links to answers elsewhere.  External links can break, in which case your answer wouldn't really contain any useful information.  We ask that you include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.